# non-nested for loop?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

How do I parallelize non-nested for loop with openmp?

Comment: @Gilles I have re-written the code. This is the complete code for the function.

Comment: At the time of writing this, no code at all is visible in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible way of parallelising this function:

```
void func1( int *seed, int *array, double *arrayX, double *arrayY,
            double *probability, double *objxy, int *index,
            int Ones, int iter, int X, int Y, int Z, int n ) {

    const int max_size = X * Y * Z;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        arrayX[i] += 1 + 5 * rand2( seed, i );
        arrayY[i] += -2 + 2 * rand2( seed, i );
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < Ones; j++ ) {
            int index_X = round( arrayX[i] ) + objxy[j * 2 + 1];
            int index_Y = round( arrayY[i] ) + objxy[j * 2];
            index[i * Ones + j] = fabs( index_X * Y * Z + index_Y * Z + iter );
            if ( index[i * Ones + j] >= max_size ) {
                index[i * Ones + j] = 0;
            }
        }
        double probI = 0;
        for ( int j = 0; j < Ones; j++ ) {
            probI += ( pow( array[index[i*Ones + j]] - 100, 2 ) -
                       pow( array[index[i*Ones + j]] - 228, 2 ) ) / 50.0;
        }
        probability[i] = probI / Ones;
    }
}
```

You will notice here that I made a few changes. Amongst them, the late declarations of the variables, such as `i`, `j`, `index_X`, and `index_Y` are very important, since the variables are now `private`. In your code, these use to be declared at the beginning of the function. You could have them declared explicitly per-thread private using a `private( i, j, index_X, index_Y )` clause to you `parallel` directive. However, declaring them inside the `parallel` region is far less error prone and I would encourage you do always do so (even when not trying to parallelise a code).

Would this code work for you?

Comment: Thank you very much! It does make sense and it works!

Comment: You might find the performance is slightly better if you write it as a `#pragma omp parallel` block with two `#pragma omp for` statements inside it. (The fork/join likely costs more than a barrier).   Alternatively, there seems to be no reason why you couldn't move the contents of the first loop inside the second i loop before the j loop. AFAICS `arrayX[i]` and `arrayY[i]`could be calculated there without that being a problem.

Comment: @JimCownie You're right. And furthermore, I wondered whether the `rand2()` function is reentrant/threadsafe, and whether `seed` would need to be declared `firstprivate` and/or initialised on a per-thread basis. Altogether, playing with what looks like random number generation in parallel, beside the performance aspect, is always a tricky business not to take lightly...